# How will the escrow system work on the Request Network?

Tags: escrow, request

On [the official Request Network website](https://request.network/#/) it says that the network will have an escrow system. However, I cannot wrap my head around how this would work without a third party. How will the escrow system work on the Request Network?

Comment: You should read the white paper. 4.5  section.